# x-ms-continuation is missing from headers when running ORDER BY r._ts DSEC CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Continuation token not being sent when running ORDER BY DSEC in query

[Screenshot of Query & Headers output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es9hr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [**`Github Issue`**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-node/issues/252),

> currently the sdk's support for continuation token has some
> limitation. You won't get continuation token for cross partition order
> by.
>
> If you change query to only target a single partition you will get
> continuation token. Maybe that helps.